# Como hacer un restore y un backup desde delphi con my sql

Tags: mysql, delphi

Yo creo la base de datos, la lleno, modifico etc pero me falta hacer la copia de esos registros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revisa el directorio donde tienes instalado **MySQL**. Debería existir una utilidad llamada **mysqlDump**, que te permitirá realizar copias de seguridad y restaurarlas desde la línea de commandos.
Desde Delphi puedes llamar a esta utilidad utilizando `ShellExecute`.

Para realizar la copia de seguridad deberías lanzar un comando similrar a este:

```
mysqldump -u root -p nombre_base_de_datos > fichero.sql
```

Para realizar la restauración, algo como esto:

```
mysql -u root -p  nombre_base_de_datos < fichero.sql
```

Comment: Gracias! asi lo solucione!

Comment: @PaulyGonzalez si así lo solucionaste, recomiendo que marques la respuesta de Germán como aceptada y además, puedes votar a favor de ella, de esta manera otros en la comunidad sabrán que esta respuesta te fue de ayuda.

Comment: Perfecto, Gracias